# __consumer_offsets topic showing different configuration when describe with zookeeper and bootstrap-server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka version - 2.4.0
I am using **kafka-topics.sh** script to describe **__consumer_offsets** topic with below 2 options

- --bootstrap-server
- --zookeeper ( which is DEPRECATED)

Both of them showing different replication factor and configuration of the topic..

Could any one help here to understand why this behaviors. Many thanks for your help.

**When using --bootstrap-server**

```
./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-broker:9092 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets

Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: compression.type=producer,min.insync.replicas=1,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600,retention.ms=60000,message.format.version=0.10.2-IV0,file.delete.delay.ms=30000,unclean.leader.election.enable=true,retention.bytes=132070253,delete.retention.ms=30000,segment.ms=3600000
```

**When using --zookeeper**

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper-host:2181/asrkafka --describe --topic __consumer_offsets

Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-Zookeeper option uses the AdminClient API which pulls additional topic metadata that is stored in the broker settings rather than only in Zookeeper.

Comment: Sometime I have seen using --bootstrap-server showing different replication factor and  cleanup.policy than the -- zookeeper. like --bootstrap-server says replication factor 2 and cleanup.policy as delete while --zookeeper report replication factor 3 and cleanup.policy=compact. could you help with this as well like what could be the case

Comment: That should never happen. Do you have more than one cluster?

Comment: Yes I do have more than 1 cluster .. but for different cluster we have different node in zookeeper.

Comment: I see you put /asrkafka, so are you always referring to the same path when you lookup the topic data? And that same path is stored in the broker settings?

Comment: I have used that .. will see later if similar thing popup again and update. Thanks